# unable to see pictures

Tags: 14.04

I have a flash drive with photos and documents on it. When I try and open `.jpg` files I get an error saying this error interpreting JPEG image file:

```
Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00 0x00
```

My windows 8 system opens them fine.

Comment: Have you ever changed the extension, which was previously set different, of the file to JPEG? Because if you get that error, it must not be a JPEG file. The file seems corrupted. In Windows, most image viewers would support viewing the file in case if any extensions given manually. But in Ubuntu, some image viewers don't support it.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on Windows and not on Linux, then the file is not a JPEG file type. The issue is in the file extension. Check out the file extension in the terminal by typing `file {filename_with_extension}`. The command will return some properties of the file. There you could check the image type. If `JPEG` is not mentioned, then you would have to change the extension to actual image type. For instance, if something like `PNG` is mentioned, you would have to change extension to `.png` from `.jpeg`. In Linux, extensions are important to consider whereas in Windows it doesn't matter of what extension has been set.